Issue with IP_HDRINCL causing client to miss packets in raw socket communication
I have a socket-based communication setup between a server and a client for my operating system project. I'm setting the IP_HDRINCL option to manually add an IP header, but this breaks communication—the server sends packets, but the client doesn’t receive them. When I disable IP_HDRINCL, the communication works as expected.
Here's the code snippet where I'm setting the option:
if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&optval), sizeof(optval)) < 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to set IP_HDRINCL" << std::endl;
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
} 

What could be causing this issue? Is there an alternative way to achieve manual IP header control without disrupting the client-server communication?

Sniff the packets on the wire for both the automatic header and your custom header.  Compare the header differences.

You only show that you set IP_HDRINCL but not the header you add. Probably the problem is not in that you add something but that what you add is somehow wrong. Also, what does mean "server sends packets" - do you see them actually going out of the server with a packet capture? So please provide more details so that one can better understand and ideally reproduce your problem.
